# What's the equivalent of `mapNotNull` that result in map?

Tags: kotlin

I can convert a `List<Int?>` to `List<Int>` using `mapNotNull` function as shown below.

```
    @Test
    fun main() {
        val testData = listOf(1, null, 3, null)
        val noNull = processAwayNull(testData)
    }

    private fun processAwayNull(testData: List<Int?>): List<Int> {
        return testData.mapNotNull{ it }
    }
```

How could I convert `Map<String, Int?>` to `Map<String, Int>`?
The below with `testData.filter { it.value != null }` doesn't works, as it still produce `Map<String, Int?>`.

```
    @Test
    fun main() {
        val testData = mapOf("One" to 1, "Two" to null, "Three" to 3, "Four" to null)
        val noNull = processAwayNull(testData)
    }

    private fun processAwayNull(testData: Map<String, Int?>): Map<String, Int> {
        return testData.filter { it.value != null }
    }
```

Comment: is it ok? `val map = testData.mapNotNull { it.value?.let { value -> it.key to value } }.toMap()`

Comment: That's one way. But I'm hoping something readily available without need to construct our own logic in the chain as above.

Comment: just make it as an extension function and you will get something short and readable in code )

Comment: @Eugene that should be an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, not really out of the box (in the sense that you get `Map<String, Int>` immediately), but what about [`filterValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-values.html)?

```
testData.filterValues { it != null } // gives Map<String, Int?> but without null-values
```

Combining or replacing that with [`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html) (maybe you can use a default value instead of `null`?):

```
// combining:
testData.filterValues { it != null }
        .mapValues { (_, value) -> value as Int }
// replacing:
testData.mapValues { (_, value) -> value ?: /* default value */ 0 }
```

Both give a `Map<String, Int>` but the first creates and fills 2 maps under the hood and the second uses `0` instead of `null`.

You can also simplify the [`filterValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-values.html)-variant with an appropriate [unchecked cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unchecked-casts), as "we know it better":

```
testData.filterValues { it != null } as Map<String, Int> // unchecked cast, because: we really do know better, do we? ;-)
```

Alternatively, you could also just handle all entries the way you knew already (using [`mapNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/map-not-null.html)) and then create a new map out of it:

```
testData.asSequence()
        .mapNotNull { (key, value) ->
            value?.let {
              key to it
            }
        }
        .toMap() // giving Map<String, Int>
```

If you require that more often you may even want to have your own extension function in place:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <K, V> Map<K, V?>.filterValuesNotNull() = filterValues { it != null } as Map<K, V>
```

Now you can use it similar as to follows:

```
testData.filterValuesNotNull() // giving Map<String, Int>
```

Comment: **+1** for the unconventional `as` cast and avoiding an extra map (or list) copy and using the type system to your advantage. Useless copies are too often unhesitatingly accepted in the JVM world...

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternative with custom helper function:

```
inline fun <K, V, R> Map<K, V>.mapValuesNotNullToMap(transformValue: (V) -> R?): Map<K, R> =
    buildMap {
        this@mapValuesNotNullToMap.entries.forEach { (key, value) ->
            transformValue(value)?.let { put(key, it) }
        }
    }
```